# Are MVVM-based applications required to have a controller?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around MVVM as I'm in the progress of learning SwiftUI development with Swift for iOS. After reading various tutorials and watching [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwGMU_Grnf8), this is my understanding:

- View: The UI
- Model: Data layer
- ViewModel: "Glue" between view and model. Contains business logic.

However, after doing additional research, I found [this article](https://cocoacasts.com/model-view-viewmodel-in-swift) which talks about the role of controllers in MVVM. Now, this confuses me a lot because my understanding was that the ViewModel in MVVM already takes care of what a controller would do e.g. in MVC and therefore controllers would not exist in apps based on MVVM.

**Question**: Do controllers exist in apps based on MVVM or is [the article](https://cocoacasts.com/model-view-viewmodel-in-swift) simply wrong?

Comment: There is no C in MVVM. What kind of answer do you want here, what kind of facts is it you are asking for?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am referring to the article I linked in my original question which claims that there are controllers in MVVM apps. Is the statement in the article simply wrong? Link to article: https://cocoacasts.com/model-view-viewmodel-in-swift

Comment: Quote from the article: "_Despite its name, the MVVM pattern includes four major components, model, view, view model, and controller._"

Comment: You can happily use MVC or any other architecture with Swift, MVVM is not required. Whatever works for your project.

Comment: Regarding your question, “why the downvotes?”, while I didn’t down-vote, it probably because the choice of terminology is often a matter of opinion. Different developers/teams have (often, strongly held) differing opinions about what precisely these various terms mean. But I agree with you, that you were asking precisely what the author was saying in that article, and as such, doesn’t warrant down-votes.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my original question and changed view to "The UI" and also changed "Swift" to "SwiftUI development with Swift" to further clarify where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is merely a question of terminology. This author’s choice of terminology is a bit unusual, and I would not get hung up on that. As you dive into these architectural patterns, you’re going to see all sorts of different uses of terminology. (Usually it is the term “view model” that is subject to some creative interpretation.)

Regarding this author’s particular use of the term “controller”, earlier in the document, when talking about view controllers, he starts referring to them as simply “controllers”. This is imprecise, but it is the terminology that he adopts throughout the article.

(As an aside, I would avoid referring to view controllers just as “controllers”, because for many of us, the term “controller” refers to something far more abstract, unrelated to the UI. E.g., see the discussion of “controllers” late in Dave Delong’s excellent video [A Better MVC](https://youtu.be/YWVzCd5FYbs). But let’s set all of that aside and talk about the role of view controllers in MVVM.)

If you are employing MVVM in UIKit or AppKit, then you have a model, a view, and a view model. But you still have view controllers, too. So what happens to them? They do not disappear (unless you switch to something like SwiftUI).

Most/many of us simply consider the view controller as part of the broader “view” layer. A view controller is a UIKit object. It configures views. It is not some abstract object, but rather is an integral part of the UI. In MVVM, it often bears responsibility for hooking up the views to the view model, etc. Regardless of what architectural pattern you adopt, the hallmark of a good view controller implementation is that it is almost entirely restricted to UI related tasks.

So, in short, in that article you reference, the author is merely saying that view controllers are still in the mix (for non-SwiftUI projects, at least). He decided to describe it as a separate layer in his MVVM diagram. Many of us just consider the view controllers to just be part of the “view” layer. It is a question of terminology.

Comment: By the way, while we’re talking about imprecise terminology, we should note that the author is running pretty fast and loose with the term MVVM, too. To some audiences, the term MVVM entails binding of UI controls to model objects (like you might see in SwiftUI, reactive patterns, or a third-party UI binding library) so that changes in models are automatically reflected in views and vice versa. That’s not what the author has outlined in that article.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your explanation. I am indeed getting started with a SwiftUI project, hence the lack of view controllers (or any other controllers at all). That's what confused me when reading about these in that article from cocoacasts.